# NumPy array with largest value on diagonal and other values shuffled

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to create a square NumPy (or PyTorch, since PyTorch code can be turned into NumPy with minimal effort) matrix which has the following property: given a set of values, the diagonal elements in each row have the largest value and the other values are randomly shuffled for the other positions.

For example, if I have `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, a possible desired output is:

```
[[4, 3, 1, 2],
 [1, 4, 3, 2],
 [2, 1, 4, 3],
 [2, 3, 1, 4]]
```

There can be (several) other possible outputs, as long as the diagonal elements are the largest value (4 in this case) and the off-diagonal elements in each row contain the other values but shuffled.

A hacky/inefficient way of doing this could be first creating a square matrix (4x4) of zeros and putting the largest value (4) in all the diagonal positions, and then traversing the matrix row by row, where for each row **i**, populate the elements except index **i** with shuffled remaining values (shuffled versions of [1, 2, 3]). This would be very slow as the matrix size increases. Is there a cleaner/faster/Pythonic way of doing it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can generate a randomized array on the first axis with `np.random.shuffle()`, then I've used a (not so easy to understand) mathematical tricks to shift each rows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

# First create your randomized array with np.random.shuffle()
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [2,4,3,1],
              [4,1,2,3],
              [2,3,1,4]])
# We use np.where to determine on which column each 4 are.
_,s = np.where(x==4);
# We compute the left shift that need to be applied to each row in order to get each 4 on the diagonal
s = s-np.r_[0:x.shape[0]]
# And here is the tricks, we can use the fast fourrier transform in order to left shift each row by a given value:
L = np.real(ifft(fft(x,axis=1)*np.exp(2*1j*np.pi/x.shape[1]*s[:,None]*np.r_[0:x.shape[1]][None,:]),axis=1).round())
# Noticed that we could also use a right shift, we simply have to negate our exponential exponant:
# np.exp(-2*1j*np.pi...
```

And we obtain the following matrix:

```
[[4. 1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 4. 1. 3.]
 [2. 3. 4. 1.]
 [3. 2. 1. 4.]]
```

No hidden for loop, only pure linear algaebra stuff.

To give you an idea it take only a few milliseconds for a 1000x1000 matrix on my computer and ~20s for a 10000x10000 matrix.